# May a girl/women receive voice lessons by a male instructor?

Tags: music, employment, chinuch-education, kol-isha

Private one-on-one lessons, not group lessons.
All Halachos of Yichud and Shomer Negiah are being kept to, so I guess the main question that remains is regarding the live Kol Isha (which is being listened to for business purposes, not pleasure, in a professional work setting).
Is there a Halachic precedent for a *heter* for anything like this?
Does it depend on if the teacher or student is married? Ishto Ba'ir?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya. Just to be clear, if this is a practical question, you should consult a Rav.